# Values gets destroyed in coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am wondering why a value passed into a coroutine gets overwrittn each time the coroutine runs. The value is "currentAmountOfEnemiesSpawned" which is declare at the top like this `private int currentAmountOfEnemiesSpawned;`

Is there something specific when using coroutines which deletes the entry?

Thanks!

```
   private IEnumerator SpawnEnemy(float secondsBetweenSpawns = 1f)
    {
        print($"Enemies to spawn is: {totalAmountOfEnemiesToSpawn}");
        currentAmountOfEnemiesSpawned += 1;
        if(currentAmountOfEnemiesSpawned >= totalAmountOfEnemiesToSpawn)
        {
            print("stopping respawn");
            StopEnemySpawning();
        }

        isEnemyReadyToSpawn = false;
        Vector2 rndPosWithin = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f));
        rndPosWithin = transform.TransformPoint(rndPosWithin * .5f);
        var spawedEnemy = Instantiate(enemyToSpawn, rndPosWithin, transform.rotation);
        spawedEnemy.name = enemyToSpawn.name;
        spawedEnemy.transform.parent = enemyParentGameObject.transform;


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsBetweenSpawns);
        isEnemyReadyToSpawn = true;

    }

    public void StartEnemySpawning(int amountOfEnemiesToSpawn)
    {
        isSpawningPaused = false;
        currentAmountOfEnemiesSpawned = 0;
        totalAmountOfEnemiesToSpawn = amountOfEnemiesToSpawn;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemy(1f));
    }
```

Comment: Well your spawn doesn't repeat until total is met. So the only way it repeats the current is reset to 0 and then called. As you haven't showed how the startenemtspawning is called id suggest your problem is your coroutine is only spawning one enemy and you repeatedly call it

Comment: I do believe the spawner is repeating once every second, its just stopping when total is met?
The script StartEnemySpawning() Is only called once! :)

Comment: Not by the code shown. Unless you shall startenemyspawning every second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentaly passed in a "1" thinking it was the time, but i passed in 1 as amounts of enemies to spawn... silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you say passing, you have a class level scoped variable named currentAmountOfEnemiesSpawned. Its the same reference so setting it from any method in that class will update it for all.

You may want to introduce a for loop up to currentAmountOfEnemiesSpawned that calls SpawnEnemy method without any need for subsequent code to update/set variable value.